# TV show/episode about a man in a cabinet containing snow which starts swirling around him

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw a show once where this man steps into a cabinet and snow starts swirling around him. Later in the show someone wipes circles on the glass and finds him. The only other thing I remember is that a woman was upset by all this.

Comment: I don't find this deserving of down votes. Sounds like a challenge. Also sounds like a [snow globe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_globe).

Comment: I remember a tv movie in the seventies where a man was brought back from cryogenic suspension, and it turned out that he had no soul as a consequence, and wreaked all kinds of havoc...does that ring any bells?

Comment: The part with the cabinet and the snow sounds like *Narnia*. The "woman" might be the evil witch, whose name escapes me at the moment.

Comment: @tlp - The evil witch was Jadis, but I doubt it's narnia; no glass to wipe, and it was a little girl, then her sister and two brothers.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens, the movie you remember is [Chiller](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088912/), from 1985.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say when you saw it, but I'm wondering if it's the "Silent Snow, Secret Snow" episode of *Night Gallery*, released in 1971.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0660834/):

> Psychiatrist Joel Winter investigates the claims of his asylum patient, hippie Gideon, that a pretty girl from a nearby farm is killing his patients./The Haslemans worry when their son becomes obsessed with snow that's talking to him.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are thinking of an episode of [*Castle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_tv_series) (ABC)? In season 4 episode 3 ["Head Case"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2006355/), the main characters find a room with bodies preserved by cryogenics, and Castle wipes circles on the glass window on one of the containers and finds a frozen guy. Several women are upset by this.

Comment: Unfortunately, not old.

Answer (score 2):

*Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*

But this is a book (multiple movie versions, though). The man(faun) is in the wardrobe-world, and the children go inside. Jadis, the White Witch gets pretty upset.

Comment: It wasn't a book.

Comment: @ScottMetz :I've seen two movies and a tv series made from it. Maybe more.

Comment: It sounds like something from The Box of Delights. 1980s BBC fantasy series. I was just reminded of it by an article on the SFX/GamesRadar website. Haven't seen it since I was a kid so can't say if there is a specific scene like this but I do remember a lot of snow and people disappearing into cabinets or wardrobes. Could it be this one?